# Add movie and check if category exists

Tags: java, spring, rest, enums

I want to create endpoint where I can add movies and add it to the database, everything is okay, but I have problem with categories.
After saving movie it should check if that category exists, if not = throw exception.
I made enum with values, but how to check if category in request, already exists?
Of course I tried to create class, repo etc. but then I can't check, because database doesn't has records.

In frontend I will create field with options, so user can't make mistake, but I think that it doesn't matter and in backend I should check anyway.

I tried like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ECategory name;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();

// TODO: add more categories
public enum ECategory {
    ACTION,
    COMEDY,
    DRAMA,
    FANTASY,
    HORROR,
    ROMANCE,
    THRILLER
}

public interface CategoryRepository {
    Optional<Category> findByName(ECategory name);
}
```

**SERVICE:**

```
@Service
class CategoryService {
    private final CategoryRepository repository;

    CategoryService(final CategoryRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    
        public Set<Category> checkCategories(Set<String> categoriesToCheck) {
            Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
    
            if (categoriesToCheck.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Categories are empty!");
            }
    
            categoriesToCheck.forEach(cat -> {
                Category category = repository
                        .findByName(ECategory.valueOf(cat))
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("That category not exists!"));
                categories.add(category);
            });
            return categories;
        }
    }
```

**@Update**
I think I could try to make this with switch, but maybe someone has better idea.

Comment: Could you also add the mentioned controller code?

Comment: What you mean ? MovieService create's new movie and uses CategoryService to save checked categories. MovieController just uses Service.
Its only an attempt, but I added some code.

Comment: _"After saving movie it should check if that category exists, if not = throw exception"_ -- that doesn't sound correct.  You want to save the movie using a non-existent category and THEN throw the exception?  Assuming a rational foreign key definition, you won't be able to save the movie.

Comment: The proposed logic doesn't make sense. You should be checking for the category prior to saving. If the category doesn't exist, reject the save or offer to create the category and then perform the save. Why would you save data and then throw an error, only to have to unwind the error? You're both annoying the user and wasting resources.

Comment: I meant before the save should be checked, if it does not exist then not to save, I wrote it wrong, it was very late :p

Comment: instead of looking at a language error, it's better to check what the problem and code are, then there will be no misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I added enum to entity, but I had to unfortunately resigne from the list.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ECategory category;
```

Category class (and repo) have been deleted, now is only ECategory - enum class.

Service looks like:

```
@Service
class CategoryService {

    public ECategory checkCategory(String categoryToCheck) {
        for (ECategory cat : ECategory.values()) {
            if (cat.name().equals(categoryToCheck)) {
                return cat;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("That category not exists!");
    }
}
```

This solution remains for this time..